# Cannot redeclare wp_update_core()

Tags: wp-admin, core

I think it's right after the WordPress update, we can't access the wp-admin to log in anymore.

> **Fatal error:** Cannot redeclare `wp_update_core()` (previously declared in C:\DWASFiles\Sites\pyromaitre\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-admin\includes\update.php:288) in C:\DWASFiles\Sites\pyromaitre\VirtualDirectory0\site\wwwroot\wp-admin\includes\deprecated.php on line 1076

What cause this? How can I resolve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably need to reinstall manually the wordpress core with the help of FTP software

1. download from wordpress.org the latest version of wordpress.
2. rename or delete the wp-admin and wp-oncludes directories
3. upload wordpress.

to be fully safe during this process you might want to add a .maintenance file before step 2 and remove it after step 3. this will put your site into maintenance mode for the duration of this operation.